# How to enable Intellij hot code swap

Tags: intellij-idea, hotswap

Intellij does not seem to be doing basic hot code swap on my installation.

For this code:

```
public class MainTest {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Breakpoint here");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Line that will get 24 modified");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First print here");
        MainTest mainTest = new MainTest();
        mainTest.method1();
        mainTest.method2();
        System.out.println("Line that I do not modify");
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on `mainTest.method1();` then modify the string at method2(), hit ctrl+s and continue to step by step. Unfortunately the runtime is not updated, old string is being printed. Full stop - compile - run does print the new string. So my conclusion is hot-swap not working.

Is there any settings I need to set to enable hot code swap?

- Ubuntu, JDK 1.6
- Intellij 10.5 Ultimate (evaluation)

Comment: I've never heard of hot swap for command line apps, only for web apps.

Comment: Coming from eclipse, which does this I would expect intellij to be able to do this as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: i was also facing lot of issues with this, and then i got to know that if you are using VM - then hot swap won't work

Comment: IDEA 2021.2 :  `Settings ->Advanced Settings -> Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running`. Adding dependency: `spring-boot-devtools`

Comment: In IntelliJ you must be in `Debug mode` for hot swap to work.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

After saving your class while waiting on your breakpoint just recompile your class with `Build -> Compile 'MainTest.java'` or press `Ctrl+Shift+F9` with the standard key bindings.

IntelliJ IDEA will then show a small dialog in which it asks you if you want to reload that class.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can I make intellij auto compile? (a much better feature would be to allow to: save without auto compile then to have compile on demand turned on by default).

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reloading-classes.html and http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugger-hotswap.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, looked for this a lot of time!

Comment: For Mac version only was necessary `Build -> Recompile 'MainTest.java'`, a little different.

Comment: What helped me really was Save Actions plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions.

Comment: You saved my days. I prefer the shortcut instead of restarts at every change, even if minor.

Comment: For Mac. command + shift + (Fn) + F9

Answer (score 34):

After below modifications and enabling hot swap, a change in a Java file took 1-2 seconds of restart time. (Initial start time is around 7 seconds for me).

I hope below method helps...

---

**First, you need to check “Make project automatically” in preferences menu.**

To open preferences menu;

you can go to top menu and click;

> IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences

or you can type below shortcut via keyboard;

> cmd + option + s

Then, you can check `Make project automatically` as in below picture;

[image]

**Secondly, you need to modify `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` registry setting as true.**

To open registry, you need to click below keyboard shortcut:

> cmd + shift + a

Type `registry` as in below picture, select `Registry`, and hit enter button of keyboard;

[image]

After `Registry` window opened, type `compiler.automake` to see `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` option, and check it as in below picture;

[image]

Then, you need to restart IntelliJ to make registry changes work.

Comment: HotSwap works for me when I debug the application and then build the project or just compile a file. However, it does not work on save even after the registry setting above was done. Is it because I'm in Debug and not Run?

Comment: @DKroot, yes - in IntelliJ you must be in Debug mode for hot swap to work.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Setting --> Select Debug --> HotSwap

[image]

Comment: Even when using this I still have to manually instruct intelliJ to recompile. This does make it a bit easier because you don't have to answer the question whether you want to reload the classes.

Answer (score 9):

There is a `Debugger > HotSwap` option in intellij 11.

Comment: There is an "Eclipse Mode" plugin, which works exactly like eclipse's background incremental compilation.

Comment: Good comment, sadly the plugin does not seem to be maintained any more http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=3822

Comment: In intellij 13 use: File->Settings->(type HotSwap in search field)

Answer (score 8):

I think you are asking about this,

1. Right-click on your java class
2. Select **Compile And Reload File**

Answer (score 7):

I wanted hotswap to automatically run every time I saved a Java file. None of the other answers did this so I just:

1. Created a macro that will run on save: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581992/14731
2. Added `Action: Hotswap` at the end of the macro (`Run -> Reload Changed Classes`)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone experiencing the same problem as me, you might have incurred in the following recent bug **affecting the 2020.2 update**: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247530?_ga=2.116305920.729836936.1599654650-984156210.1599654650

**TL;DR** As a workaround, you need to re-activate the Groovy plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on Ubuntu. I also had an apparently unrelated issue where IntelliJ gave an error about the file watch limit (my apologies that I no longer have the exact error message). To solve this later issue I did the following steps:

1. Add the following line to either `/etc/sysctl.conf` file or a new *.conf file (e.g. `idea.conf`) under `/etc/sysctl.d/` directory:

   ```
   fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
   ```
2. Then run this command to apply the change:

   sudo sysctl -p --system

Now my React components rebuild and hot swap just fine.

[Source](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit)

Comment: I have similar issue. however this (increasing file watcher) didn't help me.