# java Intellij Change variables in runtime like in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, parameters

In Intellij, i want to change the position of an object (thats is being drawn on a render method thats is being called every frame) while im debugging, like in Eclipse. 
Thing is, in Eclipse the changes are taken when you save the file, but here im not able to do it,  the file is autosaved but it doesn't take/compute the changes i made.

my code is something like:

```
public void render () {
 triangle.setPosition(1, 1);
}
```

then change it while debugging:

```
public void render () {
 triangle.setPosition(3, 3);
}
```

but nothing happens.

i dont know how can to search in google for this and if its posible like in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ you must compile changed files (shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + F9)

See:
[How to enable Intellij hot code swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402162/how-to-enable-intellij-hot-code-swap) and
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugger-hotswap.html