# Can't use Macros in IntelliJ 10 CE

Tags: macros, intellij-idea

i am using IntelliJ 10 CE for developing Java Code.
Now I trie so format my code on saving. I found an answer here on stackoverflow [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)
But when i try to replay the macro, it is disabled. 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does it work with IDEA 11? Do you have focus in the editor?

Comment: I have focused the editor, otherwise I couldn't record the Macro. I do not have installed the IDEA 11.

Comment: Now I have installed IDEA 11 and it works fine. Maybe someone knows the answer for IDEA 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 10 had many issues with processing Macros, in IDEA 11 we've reworked this subsystem which addressed a lot of known problems.