# Code reformatting on save in PhpStorm or other jetbrains ide

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, reformatting

How can I set up that the code is reformatted automatically on saving?

So I don't always have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 
<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine, but probably better for most people to use the save actions plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Actually it is possible.
The idea is to record a very simple macro that selects all the lines (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), formats (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), deselect all (Up and Down arrow) and saves a file (Ctrl+S), and bind this macro to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

**Free Ctrl+S changing keyboard shortcut for "Save all"**

1. open File > Settings;
2. search for "keymap" and open it;
3. search "Save All" and double click the action "Save all";
4. select "Remove Ctrl+S";
5. double click "Save All" again and select "Add Keyboard Shortcut";
6. select "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S" as first stroke.
7. Confirm and exit from Settings.

**Record the macro**

1. Edit > Macros > Start Macro recording
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, then <kbd>Up arrow</kbd>, then <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>, and finally then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
3. Stop recording the macro clicking on the Stop button on the bottom right of the page.
4. Give this macro a name like "Format and Save"

**Assign Ctrl+S to "Format and Save"**

1. open File > Settings;
2. search for "keymap" and open it;
3. search "Format and Save" and double click the action "Format and Save";
4. select "Add Keyboard Shortcut";
5. select "Ctrl+S" as first stroke.
6. Confirm and exit from Settings.

Finally, enjoy PhpStorm!

Comment: The macro doesn't have to be that long: Ctrl+Alt+L and Ctrl+Alt+S does the same thing as well.

Comment: Please replace "Ctrl+Alt+S" with "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S" as the latter has no conflicts.

Comment: **Useful hint to format all directory files:** First select the directory in `Project` window and then from `code` menu, choose `Reformat code`

Comment: would this work with phpstorm's auto saving feature as well? As in it would auto save + auto format without clicking any hotkeys?

Comment: PhpStorm refuses to correctly indent my lines. For example, if I mash tab and indent a line 10 times, it doesn't snap back to where it's supposed to be. I can't find out how to fix this formatting, help!

Comment: @Mkey i tested this phpstorm 2020.3 not working with autosave + auto format without clicking any hotkeys. :(

Comment: The fact that PHP Storm doesn't have a simple "format on save" preference (and the ability to map formatters for each language) is MIND BOGGLING. Use VS Code.

Answer (score 23):

I use Save Actions Plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions for PhpSorm

Answer (score 21):

**Settings** -> **Tools** -> **Action on Save** -> **Reformat code**

Answer (score 6):

Another thing that I found very helpful in combination with this macro is the

`Show Reformat File Dialog`.

In case you want to only reformat the code you just changed, you can set the option:

`Only VCS changed text`

The dialog can be opened through the following shortcut: 
`CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+L`

Comment: Thanks. The macro is useful, but this is what I needed. Most of the time, I want to reformat new/changed code.

Answer (score 1):

Checked on PHPStorm 2020 & greater versions and found a plugin named [Save Action](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions). But make sure you configure for new and exisiting projects.

You can also export your PHPStorm settings and then unzip & replace/create the following :-

1. **Macro File under Settings/Option/macro.xml**

```xml
    <application>
    <component name="ActionMacroManager">
    <macro name="Format & Save">
    <action id="ReformatCode"/>
    <action id="SaveAll"/>
    </macro>
    </component>
    </application>
```

2. **Settings/Keymaps/Default Copy.xml**

```xml
    <keymap version="1" name="Default copy" parent="Default for XWin">
    <action id="DBNavigator.Actions.SourceEditor.Save"/>
    <action id="Macro.Format & Save">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl s"/>
    </action>
    <action id="SaveAll">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="shift ctrl alt s"/>
    </action>
    </keymap>
```

Now Zip it back & import it & whenever you press ctrl+s - Auto Code Format will be done.

Answer (score 0):

From v2017.2.4 CTRL + ALT + L doesn't work. Use `alt` + `F8` instead.

Solution:
Use: ALT + F8 to format the code.

When creating a macro as described by Luca Mastrostefano, use:
`alt` + `F8` to format and then `ctrl` + `alt` + `s` to save.

Comment: That is actually specific to the `Visual Studio`-keymap in PhpStorm