# How to auto format code in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, webstorm, code-formatting

I'm looking for a way to auto-format my code in the WebStorm IDE?

Comment: I do not see anything special about it. Standard action/shortcut mentioned in "Help | Default Keymap Reference" which has only frequent actions listed.

Comment: Where is the difference to a prettier?

Answer (score 163):

**Mac**: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**PC**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This does not answer the question of "auto-formatting" code.  It still requires keypresses.

Comment: It does answer it,  usually you do not want it to format until you issue the command.   This also works in WebStorm.

Comment: This is assuming you have the standard IntelliJ keymappings.. It's Alt+F8 by default in Windows using the Visual Studio keymappings.. Which you can easily find by going to the keymap section of the settings window and searching for "format" or "reformat"

Comment: @PeteGardner it does answer

Comment: @Vad No.  Although this answer is appreciated, it is about "formatting", not "auto-formatting".  Auto-formatting, as the name implies, is automatic -- no key presses necessary.

Comment: For me, and I assume most of the people here, "auto-formatting" is what happens when you press Ctrl+Alt+L

Comment: What about Ubuntu? this shortcut is causing it to switch Ubuntu user

Comment: This is not very related to the question, the best answer is from Andrew-Dufresne to achieve auto-format on save by bind key combination to a custom macros.

Answer (score 109):

It is possible by creating a macro that formats the code and save it, and then bind this macro to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut. (Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

[This answer was posted for phpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26001409/177116) and it is equally valid for WebStorm. A modified version of answer is as follows:

---

**Record the macro**

1. Edit > Macros > Start Macro recording
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> 
   (on Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
3. Stop recording the macro clicking on the Stop button on the bottom right of the page.
4. Give this macro a name like "Format and Save"

**Assign Ctrl+S to "Format and Save"**

1. open File > Settings;
2. search for "keymap" and open it;
3. search "Format and Save" and double click the action "Format and Save";
4. select "Add Keyboard Shortcut";
5. select "Ctrl+S" as first stroke.
6. it will report conflicts. Ignore it and click OK button
7. WebStorm will show a warning "The shortcut is already assigned to other actions. Do you want to remove other assignments?" Click "Remove" button

That's it.

Comment: THIS should be the correct answer! I've always known about the keyboard shortcut but that doesn't "auto" format my code, it only formats when I tell it to (which I often don't)

Comment: I had to re-map "save all" to cmd+option+s, then change step 5 to "cmd+option+s" on OSX

Comment: Not bad, however it doesn't format other files besides the one that is currently opened in editor. All other files are saved without formatting

Comment: I used Jetbrain IDEs 2 years.... I learn new great idea Thanks

Comment: I agree. This should be the correct answer. I used this answer for a lot of years through multiple JetBrains versions. It still accurate no matter what year you are.

Answer (score 30):

"Save Actions" plugin can format code when saving.

1. Install plugin:

   File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories;

   - input keyword "Save Actions" install
   - restart the IDE.
2. Config plugin:

   File -> Settings -> Other Settings

   - check "Format file" option.

Comment: Welcome. You could make this a better answer if you provided some details about how to configure the plugin

Comment: Save Action is by far the best solution IMO. Full documentation can be found here: https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have ALT on your MAC it is:

COMMAND + OPTION + L

Comment: This does not answer the question of "auto-formatting" code. It still requires keypresses.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open **Settings**.
2. Select **Plugins** `>` **Marketplace**.
3. Enter `Save Actions` into search field.
4. Click <kbd>Install</kbd> to install plugin. Reload IDE.
5. Open **Settings** again.
6. Select **Save Actions** (it appears at the bottom of the settings list).
7. Check `Reformat file` > Press <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

[image: Save Actions JetBrains Plugin]

Visit [Plugin Homepage](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions)

Answer (score 1):

Reference https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/command-line-formatter.html#options

Format files from the command line

```
# my case in mac 
➜  bin pwd
/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/231.8770.64/WebStorm.app/Contents/bin
➜  bin ./format.sh -s ~/Default.xml  -r /xxxx
```

- Default.xml export form WebStorm.(Setting->Editor->Code Style-> Export)
- -r  set project_dir

Answer (score 0):

A slight correction on the answer based on [Code reformatting on save in PhpStorm or other jetbrains ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496669/code-reformatting-on-save-in-phpstorm-or-other-jetbrains-ide/26001409#26001409) This answer is basically correct, but you need to create a custom keybinding for `Save All` in order for it to work, and the keybinding given for Windows (or Linux), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is used to open the settings dialog which could have unwanted consequences.

---

### Change the `Save All` key binding

1. Open the settings with  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (Mac).
2. Go to `Keymap` -> `Main Menu` -> `File`->`Save All`
3. Right click and select `Remove Ctrl+S/Cmd+S`
4. Right click and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
5. Set keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Mac) and click `OK` on the shortcut window and settings window.

### Create the Macro

1. Click on `Edit` -> `Macros` -> `Start Macro Recording`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Mac)
3. Enter a name such as `Format-save`

### Setting the keybinding

1. Open the settings with  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (Mac).
2. Go to `Keymap` -> `Main Menu` -> `Edit`->`Macros`->`Format-save`
3. Right click and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
4. Enter  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>s</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (Mac) and click `OK` on the shortcut window and settings window.

And you're all set!