# Jetbrains reformat(rearrange) code automatically

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How Can I reformat(rearrange) my code in phpstorm? is there any shortkey for that or can I do it through **Search Everywhere** dialog box?

Comment: BTW -- for actions you better use `Help | Find Action...` instead of "Search Everywhere" -- it shows shortcuts

Comment: You can check my previous answer on the following post - [Click here to see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66723486/7602650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a key combination for this action but it depends on your current keymap. For example, on the "IntelliJ Idea Classic (OSX)" keymap the combination is <kbd>Alt-Cmd-L</kbd>

Open `Settings`/`Preferences`, select `Keymap` on the left list of categories and search (using the box on the top-right corner of the window) for "Reformat".

It will find you "Reformat Code" and "Show Reformat File Dialog" and you can learn what key combinations they have currently assigned (if any) and/or assign different key combinations for them if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

on a mac it's command+alt+l and you can probably find this for you here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/reformatting-source-code.html