# How enable auto-format code for Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, format, reformat

Is it possible in `Intellij IDEA` after typing `;` or at any event formatting of this string happens automatically?

For instance,
to:

```
a+b=10;
```

after:

```
a + b = 10;
```

Or only possible option: *Code > Reformat Code...*?

Thank you!

Comment: `Alt` + `c` + `r`

Comment: if you would like for this feature to be included in IntelliJ itself (not in any plugin), please vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5806

Answer (score 233):

The formatting shortcuts in Intellij IDEA are :

- For Windows : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- For Ubuntu : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Windows</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd>
- For Mac : <kbd>⌥ (Option)</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Yes, but I would like this to happen automatically without any of pressing a hotkey.

Comment: Macro? ctrl+alt+l becomes ctrl+alt+l+enter

Comment: The question expressly state "auto-format" after each line is written.

Comment: To simplify reformatting on **Ctrl+Alt+L**, you can open Settings - Editor - General and remove check mark from "Show 'Reformat Code' dialoog" check box in the Formatting section.

Comment: @axelrod is there a way to do this automatically when saving or compiling the code

Comment: That does not answer the question. The answer by Nafiur Rahman Khadem does.

Comment: This answer links to a plugin that allows such function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save

Answer (score 38):

You can do this with [Save Actions plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions)
Refer [This article on how to configure the plugin.](https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/06/10/intellij-idea-tips/)

> Save Actions plugin Supports configurable, Eclipse like, save actions, including "optimize imports", "reformat code", "rearrange code", "compile file" and some quick fixes for Java like "add / remove 'this' qualifier", etc. The plugin executes the configured actions when the file is synchronised (or saved) on disk.

1. Install the plugin
2. Go to **Settings** > **Other settings** > **Save actions**
3. Tick **Activate save actions on save**
4. Tick **Reformat file**
5. Apply > OK

[image]

I prefer the hot-keys though, For Mac,

To format the code : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt(Option)</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

And **additionally** I do,: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt(Option)</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
, This will remove unused imports and format the import list as well.

Answer (score 28):

I have found two ways to do this:

1. Go to `Settings> Keymap.`In the right portion go to `Editor Actions> complete current statement.`Click on it and select add keyboard shortcut. Press ; and select ok.
2. Use macro. Go to

`Edit> Macros> Start Macro Recording.`

Now press semicolon and keyboard shortcut to reformat code (you can find the keyboard shortcut from other answers or from settings > keymap).

After doing reformat go to

`Edit> Macros> Stop Macro Recording`

Save the macro with a name (auto format or something else). Then go to

`Settings> Keymap> Macros> auto format` (the macro name).

Click there and select add keyboard shortcut, then press semicolon and click ok. Now whenever you will press semicolon it will write semicolon and do auto format.

Comment: Nice. I also added `Shift+[` using the first method to format the line when writing `if` statements and methods and such. For some reason, `Enter` didn't seem to work, though.

Comment: This was very helpful, it's weird that Intellij doesn't have auto-reformat option at all

Answer (score 13):

Eclipse has an option to format automatically when saving the file.  There is no option for this in IntelliJ although you can configure a macro for the Ctrl+S (Cmd+S on Mac) keys to format the code and save it.

[Intellij reformat on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)

Answer (score 7):

File-> Settings -> Keymap-> Complete Current Statement

I added `;` key in there. When typing ';' at the end of the line, it is auto-formatting.

**UPDATE**

I realized that this will cause some problems in some situations. Use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead. This key can be used in any position of cursor in a line. It will add `;` at the end of the line. Also this shortcut have some other useful features.

like:

```
public void someMethod()
```

after shortcut:

```
public void someMethod() {
    // The cursor is here
}
```

so formatting on inserting `;` is not necessary.

Comment: Smart, but not for Kotlin

Answer (score 6):

This can also be achieved by Ctrl+WindowsBtn+Alt+L. This will be important to some people,because in some Virtual Machines, Ctrl+Alt+L can log you out.

Answer (score 6):

Default one is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
There is a key-mapping dialog box where you can configure/overwride all keyboard shortcuts.

Navigate File->Settings->KeyMap

[image]

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> combination *(Complete Statement)* also does the job and makes some more handy stuff with functions, cycles, etc.

JetBrains docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/completing-statements.html

Answer (score 4):

This is now available starting with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2
check [Trigger actions when saving changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.2/saving-and-reverting-changes.html#actions-on-save)
`File > Settings ... > Tools > Actions on Save` and select `Reformat code`, you can configure it to be applied to the whole file or just the changed lines.

**P.S.** you have to apply this to each project you have, it doesn't get applied to all projects.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions in Intellij is as elegant (or useful) as in Eclipse. What we need is feature request to the intellij so that we can add a hook (what actions to perform) when the IDE autosaves.

In Eclipse we can add "post-save" actions, such as organize imports and format the class. Yes you have to do a "save" or ctrl-s but the hook is very convenient.

Comment: is there any contact to intellij about htis so far? If so please post link here :)

Comment: @RuthiRuth found it ;) https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5806

Answer (score 3):

if you want, you can use a [saveActions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin. You can reformat file, optimized the imports and more things, it's really customizable and easy to setup.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's not possible, but in intellij 13, how about adding a mouse gesture, something like single left mouse click to reformat the code? Or if you don't use the mouse much then add a very simple keyboard hotkey that you use all the time (possibly the "enter"? not sure if intellij would be happy with that to be honest)

Comment: Why the downvote? I am saying that what you want is not possible, and trying to provide with the closest possible thing..

Comment: The downvote is easy to explain: Mouse click. One big advantage of IntelliJ is the shortcuts and that you don't need the mouse often. If you code much, you don't want to use the mouse much, because you are faster with the keyboard. There is a shortcut for formating already.

Answer (score 2):

In Mac it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>(assuming you haven't changed any of your [modifier keys](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25240?locale=en_US) or Intellij keyboard shortcuts from it's default state)

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment of [Larson](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5806), this is now possible with the [save-actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin.

Comment: Thank you but the question is about automatic reformat, not reformat on save.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old but there is actually a [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin for IntelliJ that can be configured to format the code automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The way I implemented automatical reformating like in Microsoft Visual Studio (It doesn't work perfect):

```
1. Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording
2. Press continuously: Enter + Ctrl+Alt+I
3. Edit > Macros > Stop Macro Recording (Name it for example ReformatingByEnter)
```

Now we need to perform same actions but for Ctrl+Alt+L+;

```
4. Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording
5. Press continuously: ; + Ctrl+Alt+I
6. Edit > Macros > Stop Macro Recording (Name it for example ReformatingBy;)
```

Now we need to assign HotKeys to these macros:

```
7. File > Settings > Keymap > press on a gear button > Duplicate...
8. Unfold a macro button (beneath) and by right clicking on two 
ours macros assign HotKeys for them: "Enter" and ";" correspondingly.
```

Comment: Might be a limitation of my keyboard, but I can only seem to record 3 keys at a time.