# How to convert code that is 1 big line to normal looking code

Tags: intellij-idea

If i have a bunch of code that is just 1 big line is there any way to convert it to normal looking code, im using Intellij.

from this:

```
public class Test {public void methodName(){System.out.println("Example");}}
```

to this:

```
public class Test {
    public void methodName(){
        System.out.println("Example");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-formatter should work for this:

The auto-formatting shortcut in IntelliJ

- For windows  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- For ubuntu  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- For Mac  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

(copy pasted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880058))

In the future, as you learn more about what keywords to look for you can find the answers to these questions yourself. I noticed in your other question you said you were still learning, so for now it's ok as long as you tried searching before asking here. That said, this is a clear question with a good example of what you were trying to do.

Comment: thanks very much, i was looking all over for this feature but as you said i didnt know of the auto formatting keyword which didnt give me the answer i needed when looking for it.