# Can't figure out how to use Prettier Plugin in .prettierrc

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using Prettier for a Java project. Prettier doesn't format Java by default, so instead I installed this plugin here: https://github.com/jhipster/prettier-java

Following the directions in the README works fine, however, I'd prefer not to type a terminal command to reformat all my java files every time I modify anything. Instead I'd like to format a file anytime I save it. This is currently in my `settings.json`:

```
"[java]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

However, using `Shift+Alt+F`, the default command for formatting in VScode, results in the error "There is no formatter for "java" files installed". How do I configure my `.prettierrc` file to properly use the plugin to format java files?

This is my .prettierrc file right now:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "prettier-plugin-java"
  ],
  "pluginSearchDirs": [
    "./node_modules"
  ],
  "overrides": [{
      "files": "**/*.java",
      "options": {
            plugins: [
                "prettier-plugin-java"
            ]
      }
  }]
}
```

Comment: hopefully, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491985/2987755

Answer (score 2):

Used same settings in `.prettierrc` and `settings.json` file
except

```
"[java]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

and added default formatter for java files as follows

1. Open command Palette... Ctrl + Shift + P (mac command + shift + P) and
2. search `Format Document With...`
3. select `Configure Default Formatter...`
4. choose `Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat`

Working sample

[image]

Now if I add following in `settings.json`

```
"[java]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

got the same issue as of yours

[image]

So the solution will be to remove above settings from the `settings.json` file.

**settings.json file**

```json
{
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.fontFamily": "source code pro, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iterm.app",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false 
}
```

P.S.
Make sure `Java Extension Pack vscjava.vscode-java-pack` is installed, used v0.12.1

Ref:

1. https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/220
2. [Beautify / Format Java code in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42940091/2987755)
3. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting
4. https://github.com/jhipster/prettier-java
5. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: But won't this use Red Hat's formatter for Java files instead? I'd like to use Prettier, since that lets me configure how formatting will work.