# Remove trailing whitespace automatically on save in Clion 2017

Tags: c++, clion

So there is already a post on how to remove trailing whitespace for IntelliJ, but there are claymores invisible to the naked eye as usual:

[Remove trailing whitespace on save in Intellij Idea (12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679842/remove-trailing-whitespace-on-save-in-intellij-idea-12)

However, there is a C++/C editor derivative of IntelliJ, which is called **Clion**, and unfortunately no such checkbox exists as in the same location as in the link. So I can't use a mine detector.

I can't find anywhere in the internet how to automatically remove trailing whitespace on save in **Cion**. If anyone knows where the setting is, please let me know. Thanks, and call me Mr. X.

Comment: Try searching the Preferences window (use the field in the top left corner) for "strip trailing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Other:

[image]