# JetBrains Rider makes a lot of whitespace changes when saving C# file

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am using JetBrains Rider 2019.1.1 with C#, and every time I alter a source file, git detects a lot of whitespace changes in ALL file that are very annoying.

The files are from a repository, and I do not know in which IDE were written (VS 2017 probably), but I do not want to reformat the file's whitespaces.

How can I tell Rider to stop messing with the whitespaces ?

I do not want to ignore whitespace changes as GitHub diff can do, I want Rider to stop making such changes.

Comment: I don't know what it is but it doesn't seem to be the default in Rider, you must have changed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended being a problem with git and the configuration of whitespaces :facepalm:

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what changes you made in Git?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: Settings → Editor → General → Strip trailing spaces on Save

Reference: [Remove trailing whitespace on save in IntelliJ IDEA 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679842/remove-trailing-whitespace-on-save-in-intellij-idea-12)

Comment: In latest Rider version it's in _Settings → Editor → General → On Save → Remove trailing spaces on: [Modified/All lines]_