# Ubuntu: Do NOT lock the screen when pressing Super+L

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, screen-lock

Whenever I press <kbd>Super+L</kbd> (or <kbd>Win+L</kbd>) on my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop, the screen gets locked. I would like to disable this behaviour. In System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->System there is a shortcut configured for Lock screen: <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd>. It works. But I couldn't find where the shortcut for <kbd>Super+L</kbd> is configured.

Background: I run Ubuntu in a virtual machine on Windows and use <kbd>Super+L</kbd> to lock the Windows desktop, making it superfluous to lock the Ubuntu Desktop. Once I unlock the screen I have to type my password twice: Once for Windows and again for Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this helpful : `http://askubuntu.com/questions/264669/how-to-change-lock-screen-shortcut-for-ubuntu-12-10`

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't helpful: As I mentioned, I found the setting where Ctrl+Alt+L is configured to lock the screen. However, I wish to find where Super+L is configured to lock the screen.

Comment: Yes, the answer below.

Comment: I can't post answer as this is closed now....: On ubuntu 20.04 (not sure about other versions), you can remove 'supe+L' shortcut in settings in 'keyboard shortcuts' under system. removing shortcut also disabled the "lock screen" key on my laptop's keyboard

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unity also has a shortcut to lock the screen, so you need to disable that one too.

[image: disable shortcut screenshot]

- Install and run CompizConfig Settings Manager
- Click "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"
- Click the button next to "Key to lock the screen."
- Disable

Comment: possible to this per Console? Bash-Line? Want use it in my sh-installer script.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: old answer, doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

While this is an old question, it still comes up as the top result for searches like "ubuntu disable win+L locking". For future reference, this answer covers a method without CompizConfig Settings Manager.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/531835/how-do-i-disable-lock-screen-keyboard-shortcut-under-unity

In short:

Run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true` to disable the lock screen.

However, this will still turn your screen black for a few seconds. This is still especially useful if you are running Ubuntu in a VM, and don't want it to lock when you lock your outer system.

Comment: Thanks! For people who use ubuntu as a development VM (i.e. everyone in my workplace) and want to limit 'bloatware' this is a much nicer solution than the accepted one.

Comment: tested `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true` and not works here in Kubuntu v20.05

Comment: what worked for me (Ubuntu 20) was using `dconf editor`, and then changing the value in this path: `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/logout` to empty (`[]`)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for `search lock` in the search bar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and found `screen locking` window. That did the trick.