# Auto code formatting in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Is it possible to `format code automatically on save`? I've seen a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save) in which a macro assigned to a shortcut is proposed but I need to be able to make this a project setting. This way, anyone joining our project doesn't have to configure a macro for himself.

In Eclipse this was easily achieved using `save actions` and putting the config files under version control. Is this possible with Android Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible other than via a macro. There is an outstanding feature request -- [IDEABKL-5806 Automatically trigger code formatter on file save](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5806) -- for such an action. There a bit of discussion on the ticket you may want to read. I recommend you vote for it. It is however a 4 year old request. And based on comments by JetBrains, it does not appear like it is a high priority item. Additional votes may change that.

In the meantime, using the auto format on commit option would be an option for you.

Finally, if you want an easier way to set up the macros on other developer's systems, the macros are stored in the file `.IntelliJIDEA/config/options/macros.xml` (see [Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) for more information on the location of the config directory). Keymaps are stored in `.IntelliJIDEA/config/keymaps/{map-name}.xml` You could copy those files over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I've fixed the first link.

Comment: The linked ticket (IDEABKL-5806) is closed as a duplicate of a ticket that is now resolved, because there is now built-in support for reformatting code on save. See cwhisperer's answer.

Answer (score 68):

Using Flutter to auto format code when saving: tick - File|Settings|Language & Frameworks|Flutter - 'Format code on save'.

Comment: How the heck do you find the "File > Settings" ? I do not have this option in Android Studio v3.6.3 at all... 

Comment: @boldnik, Android Studio "preference" settings where you will have this setting.

Comment: or simply `ctrl + alt + s` by default shortcut, at least on Windows and Linux

Comment: also this feature is only available in flutter development, AFAIK.
It is better to also check `Organize import on save` below it.

Comment: This option does not exist anymore with Flutter 1.21.0 and Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: In Android Studio 4.1.1 this option exists 

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if this question is answered elsewhere or not, in Android Studio, I can find auto-format on save for Flutter in `Preferences > Languages and Framework > Flutter` as image here.
[Autoformat on save option for Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9LiG.png)

Answer (score 12):

Another option would be download the save actions plugin from [jetbrains officials](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) (as the search inside the plugin section in IDE doesn't find it)

Next, import the downloaded JAR file through IDE settings:

*File > Settings > Plugins > Install plugins from disk*

Restart the IDE and the **Save Actions** configuration will be shown on the root of IDE Settings

Answer (score 11):

In my recent Flutter installation I found this option here [image: here]

Answer (score 3):

In mac AndroidStudio -> Preferences -> tools -> Actions on save [image]

you can set formate code on save by finding above settings

Comment: It works also on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are differences based on the version of Android Studio.
The latest version (Android Studio Flamingo 2022) does it like this:
Assuming that you have already installed the Flutter plugin which includes Dart.

Open your project

```
File -> settings -> under Languages & Frameworks -> select Flutter or Dart -> 
Select format code on save
```

Also, can be done via:

```
Tools -> Actions on Save -> Reformat code
```