# How to run the android studio formatter from the command line?

Tags: android-studio

I want to format my android project from command line.
(ex. before commit, before push or any time)

Is it possible?

(I tried 'macro', 'android studio dialog'. 
[Intellij reformat on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)
but I often forgot...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git pre-commit hook format code - Intellij/Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287683/git-pre-commit-hook-format-code-intellij-android-studio)