# git pre-commit hook format code - Intellij/Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, format, hook

This gist shows how to auto-format Java code using the Eclipse formatter at pre-commit.

Source: https://gist.github.com/ktoso/708972

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This hook will run the eclipse code formatter before any commit
# to make the source look as it's supposed to look like in the repo.

ECLIPSE_HOME=$HOME/eclipse
STYLE_FILE=$HOME/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
echo "Running pre-commit hook: run-eclipse-formatter---------------------"
echo "Will run eclipse formatter, using: $STYLE_FILE"
echo "Listing folders to run formatter on… "
code_dirs=`find . -maxdepth 3 | grep 'src/'`
for dir in $code_dirs; do
   echo $dir;
done;

echo "Launching eclipse code formatter…    "
exec $ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse \
                    -nosplash \
                    -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter \
                    -verbose \
                    -config $STYLE_FILE \
                    $code_dirs

echo "done---------------------------------------------------------------"
```

I'd like to achieve this with IntelliJ and Android Studio. How would the script look like then?

Also I guess it would be best to only run the formatter on changed files. Maybe this is useful:

```
changedJavaFiles=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep '.java$')
```

ACM stands for Added, Copied, Modified. Source: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Please comment if anything is unclear.

**Update**

My setup is Windows 10 and I'd like to use the command line tool MINGW32(Git Bash). Git version is 1.9.5 msysgit.1

Comment: did you happen to find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I did not but I'm still interested in this topic!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [IntelliJ command-line source code formatter](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter) available in IntelliJ since version 2016.3. For example (for Git Bash):

```
CHANGED_JAVA_SRC_FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep '.java$')
$INTELLIJ_DIR/bin/format $CHANGED_JAVA_SRC_FILES
```

Although Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, it seems not to support this  when the IDE is open, see comment below.

A more advanced pre-commit hook example is available in the [git-hooks-code-autoformat project in GitHub](https://github.com/michalrus/git-hooks-code-autoformat/blob/master/pre-commit).

Note that a [snap package](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/install-intellij-idea-with-snaps/) is available for Ubuntu, so it is easy to add this to a Ubuntu Git or CI server as well.

Comment: It does support it, but for some reason it doesn't work when IDE is already open

Answer (score 4):

IDEA has this built into the normal commit dialog. Just check "reformat code" and it will all happen automatically.

If you want to run the reformat part of IDEA from command line I don't think it's possible. The only think I've found that can run outside is code inspections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question. I'm on Windows and everything git related happens in Git Bash. I never used the GUI of Android Studio to commit and hence didn't know update the option to format it all. As this option exists I'm sure there is a way to run this from the command line. I'll download the Android Studio source code and dig around. If I find anything useful I'll leave another comment. Source for Android Studio can be found here: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 2):

If someone else will need solution on Windows - it took me half of the day to work, so maybe it will be usefull for someone:

ive create auto_reformat.bat, content:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%P in (`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACM ^| findstr -I "java kt"`) do %INTELLIJ_DIR%\bin\format %%P
```

and problem with multiple instances reported here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160462

solution:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Command-Line+Source+Code+Formatter

but it doesnt work for me :( - we dont have spare licenses on license server, anyway, hopefully will help someone