# Android Studio: "Optimize Imports..." and "Reformat Code..." order imports differently

Tags: android, android-studio

We're using the Eclipse code formatter.  Unfortunately the order of our Java imports changes depending on whether you run `Optimize Imports...` or `Reformat Code...` last.  One of them is alphabetical, and one of them is different (seems to do Android first, then our packages, then other Java packages).

There are a couple of ways to workaround this by having developers set up their Android Studio preferences in the same way, e.g.

1. Set up a rule to reformat on save, e.g.
   [Intellij reformat on file save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save)
2. Turn on `Optimize imports on the fly`

[image]:

Is there a way to do this as part of code formatting templates, instead of with per-developer preferences?