# Is there any Jalopy plugin, that works with Intellij IDEA 2017.2?

Tags: intellij-idea, jalopy

I want my IDEA to format code on save. I used Jalopy plugin before, but now it seems, that it doesn't work with IDEA 2017.2. Is there any other plugin or I should just properly config [this one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7148-jalopy-plugin)?

Comment: Have you tried [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) See also this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/946993/2000323

Comment: Yes, I try to use it. But it's not clear how to specify a configuration for it.