# how to have intellij google java formatter work automatically on entire project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

can anyone help me (Step by step ) to understand how to configure intellij google java formatter to work automatically on my entire project or any other kind of code formatter, I need it to work automatically every time an auto save happens or a build happens even on clean install , thank you very much for your help

Comment: just press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L` for the formatting to kick in

Comment: You need to press `Ctrl+Alt+L` to reformat the code, or check `Reformat code` every time you commit/push your code.

Comment: Is there any way to have intellij run reformat automatic ? every few minutes or on every auto save ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save