# IntelliJ adds "this" to local class variables when clicking outside of the code window

Tags: intellij-idea, this

At some point, my IntelliJ started to automatically add `this` to the final members of the class.

And it seems like it does it when clicking outside of the code window.

So it automatically changes

```
class My{
  private final Dog dog;
  ...
  dog.eat()
}
```

To

```
class My{
  private final Dog dog;
  ...
  this.dog.eat()
}
```

How can I make this stop?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Git.

Comment: Do you have the [save actions plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946993/intellij-reformat-on-file-save) installed?

Comment: @knittl  The "save actions" plugin was installed. Disabling & uninstalling it did not help.

Comment: @riorio you need to restart IntelliJ after plugins have changed.

Comment: @knittl yes, restarted it. Did not help...

Comment: @riorio any other plugins? Can you disable all plugins/start the IDE in safe mode?

Comment: @knittl I took your suggestion and started to disable different plugins. Seems like after disabling the plugin of "Swiss-AS Dev-Tools" the issue was gone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely, you have [Reformat Code, Rearrange Code, or Cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-changes-dialog.html#before_commit) enabled in the "Before Commit" config section.
It reformats the current file according to your code style settings before committing the changes.

If that's not the case, check for any plugins that might trigger such behavior on saving, such as "save action" or "swiss-as dev-tools" plugins.

Comment: The "reformat code" is turned off. The "perform code analysis" was turned on, but turning it also off, did not make IntelliJ stop this.

Comment: @riorio is rearrange or cleanup enabled?

Comment: No. only the "optimize imports". I'm adding a screenshot to the post.

Comment: @riorio and it only does this when committing through IntelliJ? In other words: when committing from the command line, `this.` is not added?

Comment: Turns out it adds the `this` even without a commit. I remove it from the code, click outside of the code window and it adds it. I'm updating the post.